# Testing equality of UIViews, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am having trouble testing equality on the Views that are set up in my project.

This is a long post, please bear with me. I have 3 separate views set up as part of the same XIB.

[image]

Each view is connected to File Owner (UIViewController) via an IBOutlet
[image]
[image]
[image]

The owner itself is a UIViewController

```
@interface PuzzleViewController : UIViewController {
```

Inside the FileOwner views are declared as:

```
IBOutlet Puzzle1 *p1;
IBOutlet Puzzle2 *p2;
IBOutlet Puzzle3 *p3;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Puzzle1 *p1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Puzzle2 *p2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Puzzle3 *p3;
```

Additionally i have

```
UIView *currentPuzzleView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentPuzzleView;
```

In .m file, upon initialization, i declare current view to be p1

```
[self setCurrentPuzzleView:p1];
```

Later, i would like to check if current view is in fact p1. This comparison fails.

```
if ([[self currentPuzzleView]  isEqual:p1]) {
```

Additionally this fails as well

```
if ([self currentPuzzleView]  == p1) {
```

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using different classes for the equality test (UIView and Puzzle1). Your currentPuzzleView should be a pointer to one of those three classes Puzzle1 Puzzle2 Puzzle3. If you definitely need to use three different classes for those puzzle views, try adding tags to them and change

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentPuzzleView;
```

to

```
int currentPuzzleViewTag;
```

set it to 1 upon `viewDidLoad:` and change the tag to appropriate when different views are selected.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a hunch but perhaps `p1` is `nil` 'upon initialization'. It really depends on where you set `currentPuzzleView` to `p1`. It could be that the outlet points to nothing (yet).

Comment: This is insightful! Let me test it